# Node.js won't load Let's Encrypt certificates

Tags: node.js, lets-encrypt

```
  https_options:
   { key: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem',
     cert: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem' }
```

I just do https.createServer with the above options and get this error:

```
_tls_common.js:134
      c.context.setCert(cert);
                ^

Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:134:17)
    at Server.setSecureContext (_tls_wrap.js:1017:27)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:897:8)
    at new Server (https.js:61:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:84:10)
    at startWWW (myserver.js:192:9)
```

I tested the key/cert pair like this: (as others suggested in other questions, blog posts, forum threads)

```
openssl x509 -text -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
openssl rsa -text -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
```

Both commands printed multiple lines of seemingly valid output.

```
lsb_release -a | grep Description
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
```

do the same for the cert too .(eg read in utf8 encoding)

Comment: oh I was supplying the name of a file not the contents, so silly of me